# Apache reverse proxy double trailing slash

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a reverse proxy setup in my virtual host. However, when I visit the site: `https://example.com` instead of `https://example.com/` in the browser address bar, I get `https://example.com//`. Why do I have two trailing slashes? Is there something wrong with my apache conf? (supplied below) or is the trailing slash something that might have been added by apache conf/.htaccess by a site that is behind a reverse proxy?

My current setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass / https://example.proxy.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://example.proxy.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I visit the site: `https://example.com` instead of `https://example.com/` in the browser address bar, I get `https://example.com//`.

These two requests, with and without the trailing slash, are really the same thing. The browser will send the same request to your server in both cases. So, it's difficult to see why you would get a different response in these  two cases, unless there was some local caching issue?

(See my answer to the following question on the Pro Webmasters stack for more information with regards to how the browser handles the trailing slash on the domain: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser)

However, the `RewriteRule` directive in your `<VirtualHost *:80>` container will *always* result in a double slash - so maybe you are seeing a cached response (or browser auto-completion) from this earlier (erroneous) redirect? Note that 301 redirects are cached hard by the browser.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

In a *virtualhost* context, the `$1` backreference will capture the slash prefix on the URL-path (this differs from a *directory* or `.htaccess` context).

You need to either remove the slash in the *substitution*, or take the first slash out of the captured pattern (or use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(No need for the end-of-string anchor, since `*` is greedy by default.)

And make sure your browser cache is cleared.

Comment: No, I get the same response with two slashes. Maybe I haven't been clear, sorry :( But thanks for the explanation, and yes, the new pattern in rewrite rules resolves the problem! There are no more two slashes at the end.